# This blue vs This blue one

Tags: pronouns

I have read in my grammar book that after colour adjectives we can often leave out **one/ones** in answers. But what about questions? Are all following questions good?

> Which car is yours? **This blue, or that red?**
>
> Which car is yours? **This blue one, or that red?**
>
> Which car is yours? **This blue one, or that red one?**

Comment: These are all correct.

Comment: No, they're *not* all correct. You need the noun "one" in *every* case. Outside of *certain speakers* in extremely sloppy casual conversational contexts, you can't just use adjectival "blue" and "red" as nouns in contexts like this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers They're not all correct, but "Which shirt do you prefer, ***the blue*** or ***the red***?" is perfectly acceptable, even outside sloppy casual conversational contexts.

Comment: Note that in a very similar context, your wine waiter might ask *Which wine would you like? The red or the white?* But that's effectively "licensed" by the fact that we routinely use "red" and "white" as nouns referring to two different types of wine. There's no equivalent "standard nomenclature" for red cars and blue ones (they're certainly not "reds" and "blues" :)

Comment: This is a good question.  "This blue or that red" feels very unnatural, but it's difficult for me to say exactly why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm struggling to fault these from a grammatical standpoint, yet they don't sound natural to me as a native British English speaker. I think the reason they sound weird is that you are using 'this/that' to differentiate between the cars but also bringing their colour into it. When we use 'this' and 'that' it should be clear what or who we mean. For example, we might point to something nearby and say "this one?" or point to something in the near distance and say "that one?". If we used that method to identify a car, the colour would be irrelevant.

If faced with distinguishing between just two vehicles of different colours, we could ask, without any need to point, "is your car the *red*, or the *blue*?". It would be equally common to ask "the *red one* or the *blue one*?"

Alternatively, if faced with distinguishing between two vehicles of the *same colour*, it would be necessary to identify which car you were referring to in some other way, such as pointing or gesturing at them. For example, you might ask "*this* red one, or *that one*?", as you point to each in turn.

I can't imagine a situation where any of your examples would be used, or at least lead to a satisfactory answer. Imagine a scenario where you had been told your friend owned a red car, but you saw two red cars. If you pointed to one of the red cars and asked "is it *that* red one?" because you genuinely did not know which car belonged to them, you'd surely just be pointing to a random car and guessing? You would surely just ask "which red one?". If you did want to take a guess, the colour would still be irrelevant because that has been established.